# PHP PDO transaction SELECT issue after INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a PHP PDO Transaction than inserts a row and then selects it. When the INSERT action is done, I call another function which executes the SELECT. The issue is that the SELECT does not return the previous inserted row when executed inside the called function.

Here you have the code:

```
class FinderMyTable {

  function myfunction(...) {
    $db = DatabaseManager::getInstance()->getConnection();
    $db->beginTransaction();
    try {

      $dbParameters = array(':var1' => $var1, ...);
      $dbStatement  = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO MyTable(...) VALUES(:var1, ...)');
      $success = $dbStatement->execute($dbParameters);
      if (!$success) throw new Exception('internal-database-error');

      $insertedRowId = $db->lastInsertId();

      $dbParameters = array(':insertedRowId' => $insertedRowId);
      $dbStatement  = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = :insertedRowId');
      $dbStatement->execute($dbParameters);
      $row = $dbStatement->fetch();

      error_log('ROW: ' . print_r($row, true) );

      $rowData = $this->obtainRowData($insertedRowId);

      $db->commit();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      $db->rollBack();
      error_log($e->getMessage());
      throw new Exception('internal-database-error');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $db->rollBack();
      error_log($e->getMessage());
      throw $e;
    }
  }

  function obtainRowData($insertedRowId) {
    $db = DatabaseManager::getInstance()->getConnection();

    $dbParameters = array(':insertedRowId' => $insertedRowId);
    $dbStatement  = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = :insertedRowId');
    $dbStatement->execute($dbParameters);
    $row = $dbStatement->fetch();

    error_log('ROW INSIDE FUNCTION: ' . print_r($row, true) );

    $data = $row['field1'];
    // ...
    return $data;
  }

}
```

As you can see, I have put 2 `error_log(...);` calls.
The "ROW" call returns the correct data that has been inserted:

```
ROW: Array
(
    [id] => 813
    [0] => 813
    [field2] => 289
    [1] => 289
    [field3] => value
    [2] => value
    [field4] => value2
    [3] => value2
)
```

The "ROW INSIDE FUNCTION" call returns incorrect data:

```
ROW INSERTED FUNCTION: Array
(
    [id] => 2345
    [0] => 2345
    [comment] =>
    [1] =>
)
```

**As you can see, none of the values obtained in the last call corresponds with the inserted row.** Furthermore, I have a "comment" field which does not appear in this table!

Below you have my DatabaseManager class, which is a Singleton class that manages the PDO connection:

```
final class DatabaseManager {

  private static $instance = null;
  private $connection;

  private function __construct() {
    try {
      $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=...;dbname=...;charset=latin1', 'user', 'pass');
      $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      error_log($e->getmessage());
      die();
    }
    $this->connection = $connection;
  }

  public function __clone() {}

  public static function getInstance() {
    if (self::$instance === null) self::$instance = new DatabaseManager();
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function getConnection() {
    return $this->connection;
  }

}
```

What can be the problem?
Why the called function selects a total different row?

Comment: at first change your fetch to `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. it gives you without repeat. and use `Select SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id ON (:insertedRowId)` and use bindparam with implode to get all ids

Comment: Nobody knows what's wrong with your code. Especially when you post a deliberately artificial code. You have to create a *verifiable* examplde to get an answer. [How to create an MCVE for a PDO related problem](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: @MehemmedRustemzade I am afraid you just don't understand the question at all.

Comment: when you echo last inserted id gives you something?

Comment: @MehemmedRustemzade When I echo `$lastInsertedId` it gives me a correct integer number which is the generated "id" for newly inserted row. `$lastInsertedId` has the same value inside `myfunction(...)` and inside `obtainRowData(...)`

Comment: I don't understand why you are not using bindparam? whith bindparam you can get what you whant.

Comment: @YourCommonSense My question has a modified code to make it generic enough. I have found several questions regarding PDO and PHP in StackOverflow and no one of them follows MCVE. My problem is that the called function does not return the same result for the SELECT. In any case, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The `obtainRowData()` function has exactly that code. The `// ...` part can be removed if you want. The `obtainRowData()` function code is inside my question.

Comment: Ops sorry forgot to scroll

Comment: @MehemmedRustemzade There is no need for "bindparam". The way I am binding parameters works in PDO for all queries I have in my application. `$dbStatement->execute($dbParameters)`.

Comment: **Something else is going on here:** Look at your `print_r()` dumps that are both supposed to be showing the result of a `SELECT *`, they are not even returning the same column names, so I dont think you are actually running what you say you are running. You must be actually looking at another table in your function

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry, but this is the exact same SELECT. No difference. In my question I am explaining that both `print_r()` give 2 total different results, which is something I do not understand why. Maybe a PDO transaction issue? Maybe the PDO Singleton class is not returning the same PDO instance? Maybe is MySQL configuration the problem?

Comment: It can only be that you are SELECTing from 2 different tables, its the only possible answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Solved! Ok, I simplified so much the code ... Between the `$row = $dbStatement->fetch();` and the `error_log(...);` there were some lines of code and one of them overrided the `$row` variable. So both SELECT gave the same result from the beginning, the `error_log(...)` was done over an overwritten variable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved! Ok, I simplified so much the code ... Between the `$row = $dbStatement->fetch();` and the `error_log(...);` there were some lines of code and one of them overrided the `$row` variable. So both SELECT gave the same result from the beginning, the `error_log(...)` was done over an overwritten variable.